# Confused over wp-config.php and 'database user + database password + name'

Tags: database, wp-config

I have a domain with a subdomain.

Each of those has a different install of WordPress.

When I created the databases I made the following:

Main Domain = database called: maindomain
Sub Domain = database called: subdomain

I applied the SAME database username to both databases....

So all nice and simple....

However, why is the Database Password the same?

```
/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'passwordhere');
```

When I reset the password for the database username (which I had forgotten) it made my main domain crash?

So I guess my question is - have I just merged two databases together? Is that even possible?

Hope thats clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I applied the SAME database username to both databases
>
> Why is the Database password the same?
>
> When I reset the password for the database username it made my main domain crash?

It sounds like you created a single MySQL user which is allowed to access both `maindomain` and `subdomain` databases. When you change the MySQL user password, you need to update the password in any `wp-config.php` files where that user is set.

> Have I just merged two databases together? Is that even possible?

Based on your description, it sounds like you just need to update the password in the `wp-config.php` on your `maindomain` site. It is possible to make your `maindomain` and `subdomain` sites point to the same database but you would do that by setting the `DB_NAME` define and `$table_prefix` variable exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

The password belongs to the user, not the database. You have multiple databases, but just one user.

You *can* also have multiple installs share the same database, you just need a unique `$table_prefix` for each install.

Answer (score 0):

The credentials you enter in your wp-config files are the credentials you need to require to access WordPress database. Wordpress need 4 things to check the tables that are made for any particular WordPress installation.
1. DB name
2. DB Username
3. DB Password.
4 DB Prefix.

Here in the above table the username and passwords are the database user and database prefix is the unique prefix that is attached to all the tables in WordPress installation. I hope this clears your query.